# AppwriteException: Invalid query:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, database, appwrite

Here I am trying to run this query and it is giving me error. I don't understand why it is a bad request. I am trying to get the specific user from the database using accountId. Please help

**This is the function to call the get current user**

```
export async function getCurrentUser() {
  try {
    const currentAccount = await account.get();

    if (!currentAccount) throw Error;
    const currentUser = await databases.listDocuments(
      appwriteConfig.databaseId,
      appwriteConfig.userCollectionId,
      [Query.equal("accountId", [currentAccount.$id])]
    );
    console.log(currentUser);

    if (!currentUser) throw Error;
    return currentUser.documents[0];
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("from getCurrentUser");
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

**this specific line is not executing **

```
[Query.equal("accountId", [currentAccount.$id])]
```

**this is the error **
[image: Error message]

**this is the response**
[image: request response with the query]

note that without [Query.equal("accountId", [currentAccount.$id])] this line the request is working fine. giving me response of

[image: without the query]

please help!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are using **appwrite: 14.0.0** | Just downgrade this to **13.0.2** | Go to your package.JSON and replace this **("appwrite": "^14.0.0")** with **("appwrite": "^13.0.2")** and install the dependencies again **(npm i).**

Everything will solved.

[appwrite in package.jason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF48Q.png)